# stuck with haml templates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xhtml, haml

I want to transform some haml (*.html.haml files) into xhtml. The haml command says "Usage: haml [options] [INPUT] [OUTPUT]". So I tried it with the following response:

```
Exception on line 1: undefined method `content_for' for #<Object:0xb730af2c>
```

I noticed that there are different formats which are all called haml. I noticed one which uses angle brackets a lot. Do I need some kind of preprocessing?

Here is a sample html.haml file that I want to transform:

```
- content_for :head do
  = stylesheet_link_tag    'jquery.autocomplete'
  = javascript_include_tag 'jquery.autocomplete'
- javascript_behaviour '$("input#user_full_name").autocomplete("project_roles/auto_complete_for_user_full_name")'
```

Note: I know how to google so I am looking for specific advice.

Comment: You'd need to run it in a Rails environment in order to use Rails helpers, plus that looks like it'd need to be rendered with a layout as well.

Comment: Why not add this as an answer?

Comment: are you talking about "rails console" or "rails runner"? How would I invoke haml in this context so that it executes the haml file?

Comment: Just noticed you want XHTML. For a whole lot of reasons (see http://hixie.ch/advocacy/xhtml for some of them), that's a bad idea. Use HTML 4 or 5 if at all possible.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a rails helper, content_for, so when you invoke haml using the command line program it doesn't know what does it stands for.
So either add the haml gem to your gemfile and save the template in a .html.haml template and try to render it or replace the content_for with the html result generated by rails.

Comment: thanks everybody I decided to go for manual translation of the haml files. It is a lot of work but in this way I do not need to understand the whole rails stack.

Comment: No, in fact, you *do* need to understand the whole Rails stack in order to translate the Rails helper methods. Just use `rails runner` or something and do it right. Better yet, keep the Haml if you can.

Answer (score 0):

What you wanted is to convert Haml to Erb - the Ruby templating language which looks like HTML. Haml doesn't do that, so it tried to *render* your haml template into xhtml instead of converting it to another template.

You could have used the [haml2erb](https://github.com/elia/haml2erb) gem to do the conversion. It would go like this:

```
Dir["**/*.haml"].each do |filename|
  File.open(filename.gsub(/haml$/, 'erb'),'w') do |f|
    f.puts Haml2Erb.convert( File.read(filename) )
  end
end
```